# Calculating percentage of selected values from total values in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables, 
One table is similar to this

Table X:

A - adidas

B - puma

C - American Eagle

.

.

Another table is

Table Y:

adidas

UCB

abc

American Eagle

spykar

I want to find ratio of "number of rows in X which have their brand present in Y" to total number of rows in X

Can i do this in a single sql statement

select count(*) from X, Y
where UPPER(X.brand) = UPPER(Y.brand)

/ 
select count(*) from X

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates, you can do:

```
select count(y.brand) * 1.0 / count(*)
from X left join
     Y 
     on UPPER(X.brand) = UPPER(Y.brand);
```